# Responsive CSS not working in Django project

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I am using Django for my project. I have given CSS links in my html files like ,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/sideCart.css' %}">
```

My normal CSS are being rendered , but my responsive CSS are not being rendered in , " Device Toolbar " mode. It renders in just inspecting site normally.

I have given responsive CSS code as follows:

```
@media  (max-width : 920px){
 .sideBar{ display : none ; } 
}
```

( EDITED )
I tried in the "device toolbar" , using max-width 980px and same display none  , and its working . But max-width less than 980px , eg max-width : 979px is not working . So, its not working in less than 980px. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Try to hard reload if file is getting rendered then it's probably becouse of browser caching

Comment: hard refresh is not helping.. i tried my responsive in my php project ...its working in "device toolbar " mode  .. but not in this django project

Comment: i just fixed this by adding a meta tag. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px){
   .sideBar{ display : none ; }
}
```

Comment: Nope , still not working